How to create proxies with Xray Core (ISP/Residential)
Hello I am quite new to this area and I'm wondering If someone can guide me on building a proxy service. I currently spend hundreds renting out proxies in the form:
IP Address;Port Number; Login ID;Password
I use these proxies to re route my traffic so I don't get rate limited, and also to make unique selenium sessions. I want to be able to generate thousands of unique proxies. I also want to create residential, ISP proxies in different regions.
My current plan is to rent out VPS servers in different regions, downloading Squid/3Proxy/Xray software on each server. I also thought of docker containerization. Can anyone point me in the right direction. The image below is an example of what I purchase, and what I aim to build.
UPDATE
@Reza Gharabaghi recommended using Xray and 3x-ui on VPS servers to make residential proxies. 3x-ui has an API that I can request to the current host on a local port. Im assuming I can follow these steps (please correct me if I'm wrong): adding new inbounds through 3x-ui -> setting random "Listen IP" and random "Port" numbers -> and adjusting "Total Flow" (if I want the proxies metered)
The approach above creates residential proxies, how can I make ISP proxies though? Can I even use Xray Core to make ISP proxies?
difference between ISP and residential proxies
SideNote: If anyone has some technical knowledge on making residential proxies rotate I would appreciate any tips.



I am quite new to this area

I suggest you to use Xray instead. Much better than Squid and 3proxy.
Xray supports multiple protocols. For example you can use WireGuard.

https://github.com/XTLS/Xray-core
https://xtls.github.io/en/config/
https://github.com/MHSanaei/3x-ui


I appreciate the tip, can you please give me a high level overview or explain how I can use each one of these tools to setup the service I explained in the question. For example I know I must start by renting VPS servers in different regions, download Xray and configure its config.json file. But how do I get to the point where I have these different types of proxies (in the image) that can be metered or unmetered?

3x-ui is a panel for managing Xray connections. Using 3x-ui is super simple and straightforward. Take a look at this tutorial.

Ok cool. So to generate thousands of unique proxies can I follow these steps: Use API to create Inbounds, each Inbounds will be assigned to a random "Listen IP" and random "Port" Number. To make the proxies metered/unmetered I can add in a value for "Total Flow". Does this sound like a good start, or is there something I should do differently? Also this creates residential proxies, how can I make IPS proxies.
